# Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(1/x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(1/x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$.

We are probably going to have to use the definition of the limit here, so we have to show that $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta \quad 0 < x < \delta \quad \implies \quad |f(1/x) - L|< \epsilon$$ and $$\forall \epsilon, \exists M >0 \quad x > M \quad \implies |f(x)-L| < \epsilon.$$

I am unsure how to find the $M$ and $\delta$ here.

Comment: Hint: if $0 < x < \delta$, then $\frac{1}{x} > \frac{1}{\delta}$.

Comment: @MGA I don't see how that helps.

Comment: Look at @Wilf-Fine's answer ... essentially you have to choose $M=\frac{1}{\delta}$.

Comment: @MGA Out of curiousity, is this the only possible $M$ we could've chosen? Also, this is only true given that one of the limits exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(1/x)$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then, by the definition of limit, 
$$\exists\delta>0,\forall x\in(0,\delta)\qquad |f(1/x)-L|<\epsilon$$

So, for $M=1/\delta$

$$\forall x>M\qquad|f(x)-L|=\left|f\left(\frac1{1/x}\right)-L\right|<\epsilon$$

as $1/x\in(0,\delta)$

Comment: I don't see how $|f(x)-L| = |f(1/x) - L|$.

Comment: My bad. I edited it to $\frac1{1/x}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $r=1/x$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} f(1/x) = \lim_{1/r \to 0^+} f(r) = \lim_{r \to \infty} f(r)$